# Sleep while bit NOT set

Tags: c

How do I do the opposite of this:

```c
while((*i2s) & (1<<19))
    usleep(10);
```

I want to keep sleeping while the 19th bit is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` not operator reverses a condition:

```
while(!((*i2s) & (1 << 19))) {
    usleep(10);
}
```

Comment: While correct, it is not an easy read. In Daniel's version it is clearer that you want the bit to be 0.

Comment: What you want is the for the condition to be false; thus ! is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(((*i2s) & (1<<19)) == 0)
    usleep(10);
```

of course.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **!** operator will negate your expression:

```
while(!((*i2s) & (1<<19)))
    usleep(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the opposite of something, use !

```
while(!((*i2s) & (1<<19)))
   usleep(10);
```